# Visual C++: memory debugger refresh while running

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual C++ 2015, the memory debugger window shows

> "Unavailable when debuggee is running."

when the process is running.

Is it possible to show and reevaluate the memory at a certain address without pause the process, like a *live view*?

Comment: Like with a RAM disk/drive?

Comment: You can get a memory dump of the process at an arbitrary time without attaching a debugger and having it stop at a breakpoint (ie it'll pause for the shortest time it can); which you can then use to locate your address.  Is that sufficient?

Comment: @UKMonkey more or less. I'd like something like I set the address on the heap, and once a second it refreshes the memory at that value, flashing red the bytes changed. The VTT's answer seems good only for single variables, but I'd like to monitor a pretty large array of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Place a breakpoint, open breakpoint settings button (gear) and set action to print log message containing the value of variable of interest such as `{var_name}`. Example:

```
auto i{0u};
for(;;)
{
   ++i;
}
```

[image]

will print the value of `i` into VS output window every 10000 iterations.

This screenshot if from VS2017, but it should probably work for VS2015 as well.